# Similarity of triangles in a circle

Tags: geometry, circles, triangles

The problem:

c is a circle with a diameter AB. t is the tangent at the point B. Now C and D are two points on t and at different sides of B. I draw the line segments AC and AD, the point where AC crosses c is named E and the point where AD crosses c is named F. Show that the triangle ACF is similar to EDA.

I have made many approaches to this, but none of them is really helpful.

Comment: Are $C,D$ points *on* the tangent $t$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen yes, I forgot that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\alpha = \angle BAC$ and $\beta = \angle BAD$. Observe that $AC = AB / \cos \alpha$, $AD = AB / \cos \beta$ (follows from definition of $\cos$), $AE = AB \cdot \cos \alpha$ and $AF = AB \cdot \cos \beta$ (follows from graph of $r = \cos \theta$ in polar coordinates). Bearing in mind that $\angle A$ is common for both triangles, this is sufficient to show similarity.

Answer (score 0):

BAC would be similar to BAD because after cos, BAC would be inserted and so work out the rest of the equation and the answer would be: A= BAC+BAD.